# why text_en doesn't work on type : "vegetable" in arangosearch example

Tags: arangodb, aql

i was doing the example provided in the first page of arangosearch in manual of arangodb which is we have a set of documents about foods with two fields : name and type
in the aql query when i set
`search analyzer(doc.type == "fruit" , "text_en")`
it just works fine , but when i change the value from "fruit" to be "vegetable" it just returns an empty array , text_en is set in indexing time and it is showing it in the configuration of the view , it only works if i change the value back to fruit or use "identity" instead of "text_en"
why is that ? any solutions ?
link to the manual :
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/arangosearch.html#search-expressions-with-arangosearch-functions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so apparently "text_en" turns "vegetable" to "veget" (stems it) and stores it like that in the view , if "text_en" is also applied to the entry value , it works , for example :
`search analyzer(doc.type in tokens("vegetable" , "text_en") , "text_en")`